# How to change documents to another category painlessly

Tags: nodes

I have 4 content types eg Parts, Service, Marketing, and Sales.

I've now created one category with 4 content types sub-categories instead.

Is there a painless way of changing each documents category?

I've experimented with `[Node_export][1]` but that did not allow me to import into a different category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Node Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert), it allows you to change one content type to another:

> Node Convert adds a menu tab "Convert" on the node view page, i.e.
>   node/1/convert, which gives the ability to convert the node from its
>   current node type to another node type. The module provides the means
>   to transfer all the field values of the current node type into fields
>   on the destination node type, or discard them.

Then you can use [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to do it in batches.